# How to put this certain command into unity linux

Tags: linux, format, chromebook

What is the format/exact line in unity linux to add setxkbmap and synclient FingerLow=1 FingerHigh=5 in my .bashrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'setxkbmap
synclient FingerLow=1 FingerHigh=5' >> ~/.bashrc
```